# How can a ListAdapter know when its Detached?

Tags: java, android, listview, gridview, listadapter

How can the `firstAdapter` know when it is detached from being the listView's actual adapter (because `secondAdapter` replaces it)?

```
final ListAdapter firstAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    this,
    new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] {"AAA"},
    new int[] {android.R.id.text1}
);
final ListAdapter secondAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    this,
    new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(),
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    new String[] {"AAA"},
    new int[] {android.R.id.text1}
);

setListAdapter(firstAdapter);

(new Timer()).schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        setListAdapter(secondAdapter);
      }
    };
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(r);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no direct method/callback for this ... but ... first solution is to make own method for this and call it after you swich the adapter ... dig into `AbsListView` / `ListView` source (especially `setListAdapter` method) ... and check if `unregisterDataSetObserver` of adapter could be usefull

Comment: should be "or dig" instead "dig" ... and `setAdapter` not `setListAdapter` ... but yeah, overriding `unregisterDataSetObserver` in own adapter implementation may be useful ... as you can see **[here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java#L468)** setAdapter is using this method on "old" adapter before setting new one

Comment: Thx, that works, if you write an answer i can accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the first Adapter gets notified when it's deregistered from the ListView, so I am using: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#unregisterDataSetObserver(android.database.DataSetObserver)

```
@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
  super.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);

  Log.d("Adapter just got unregistered from the listView!");
  [...]
}
```